# ZedGraph: How to add time (usecs) in X-Axis (not date)

Tags: c#, time, scale, zedgraph

Currently my graph only shows the index in the x-axis and current in y-axis.
Now I added additional parameters (NumberOfPoints =1024, TimeImtervall = 0.0003s) to the graph-function.

What I finally want is that the x-axis show time-values and not the index.

But I the only examples I found where how to add a date.

It has something to do with the "XAxis.Type" and "XAxis.Scale.Format" but I haven't found out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want date/time I think you need to use [XAxis.Type](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_AxisType.htm) `Date` or `DateAsOrdinal`. In this case `XAxis.Scale.Format` should work, e.g. set to "HH:mm".

http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/default.html

Comment: Hi,but i dont have HH mm or ss.
My scaling is in mucroseconds from 0 to 0.3072s
How to define this?
Thx

Comment: I think it uses the same format as DateTime.ToString(), so it can show milliseconds; `"HH:mm:ss.fff"`, for you then `"ff"` or `"fff"` is probably ok. This of course assumes your X value is in fact a DateTime. If you need the 4th digit I think you need to handle it manually in the `OnXScaleFormatEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GraphPane myPane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;

        myPane.XAxis.Title.Text = "Time(sec)";

        myPane.XAxis.Scale.Format ="f4";
        myPane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Linear;

        myPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = 0;
        myPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = 0.3072;

        myPane.AxisChange();

        zedGraphControl1.Invalidate();
    }
```

You need to zoom in to see the graph in `milli` & `micro` seconds.

**`Edit:`**

[Customize the zedgraph scale format](http://zedgraph.dariowiz.com/index980a.html?title=Customize_the_scale_format)